# Is there a way BULK INSERT from local Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: sql, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, bulkinsert

TL;DR I am trying to point SQL to `BULK INSERT` from **Local** Azure Blob Storage

The problem:

Hi all,

I'm trying to connect my local SQL Server database instance to the blob storage emulator as an external connection, however I'm getting a ***"Bad or inaccessible location specified"*** error. Here are the steps I'm taking:

I have created the following `MasterDatabaseKey` and `CREDENTIALS` as follows:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE name = '##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##') 
DROP MASTER KEY;

--Create Master Key
CREATE MASTER KEY 
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='MyStrongPassword';
```

and database credentials:

```
-- DROP DB Credentials If Exist
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_credentials WHERE name = 'credentials')
DROP DATABASE SCORED CREDENTIAL credentials;

--Create scoped credentials to connect to Blob
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL credentials
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 
'Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=='; --local storage key
GO
```

then I created the following External Data Source:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE external_source
WITH 
(
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/container/some_folder/',
    CREDENTIAL = credentials
)
```

But when I run the `BULK INSERT` command:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[StagingTable] FROM 'some_file_on_blob_storage.csv' WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'external_source', FIRSTROW = 1, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

but it fails and returns

```
Bad or inaccessible location specified in external data source "external_source".
```

**How can I load a file from Local Blob Storage into SQL Server?**

Comment: Just confirming that if you plug http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/container/some_folder/ into your local browser, you get something that looks "blobby".. even a 401 error?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that is correct, 401 (Unauthorized) with an XML body.

Comment: I notice the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=dedicated#examples-bulk-operations say _Do not add a trailing /, file name, or shared access signature parameters at the end of the LOCATION URL when configuring an external data source for bulk operations._

Comment: the example also doesn't have a trailing `/` so try removing it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've just added a SAS to the `credential` parameters and appended the file with the secret. It seems to be reading the file, but it's locked by another process (apparently)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Any updates? I did not had issue when using my hosted azure storage's location, but if I try locally with http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/container/some_folder/, I'm getting similar issues as yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nick.McDermaid has point out the error correctly. From your code and the error message, the error is caused by the wrong LOCATION syntax:

- **Do not add a trailing /, file name, or shared access signature
  parameters at the end of the LOCATION URL when configuring an
  external data source for bulk operations.**

Ref here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=dedicated#examples-bulk-operations

Change value to `LOCATION = 'http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/container/some_folder'`, the error should be solved. I tested and all works well.
[image]

For you another question, we can not answer you directly. I suggest you post another question with you detailed code. We're all glad to help you.

**Update:**

About your another question, I tested and found that we must set the Shared access signature(SAS) 'Allowed resource type' = **Object**, then we can access container and child folder and the files in the container.

[image]

Example, both the statements work well.
[image]

HTH.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it only solves one portion of my problem. My use case requires that a file within a folder is read in a container, and granting permissions as such would be troublesome.

Comment: How did you create or configure the SAS permission right now?

Comment: I have set it up at FOLDER level (within the container), not sure if the SAS will grant access to child resources of said folder?

Comment: @DylanSmyth Yes, it can. We need set 'allow resource type' to `Object`. Please see my update.

Comment: not working in my case if location is of local azure storage emulator